# Link multiple border/textblock combinations to one event C#

Tags: c#, xaml, events, event-handling

I'm working on a project and have a question to optimize my C# code.
I have 30 rows and 15 columns, the first column contains keywords and the next 14 columns to the left contain all kind of calculations for that keyword. 
Now I need to be able to click on a keyword so every calculation form that row is highlighted in another color, and only that row.
My buttons are build with a xaml border + textbox combination and look like this:

```
    <Border x:Name="x_1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonUp="btn_1">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">beloof</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="x_2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand"
          MouseLeftButtonUp="btn_2">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Ivory" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">televisie</TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

These are 2 examples of the calculations in xaml code, I read them out of the xml file with xpath and they are build that their x:Name is "number" + row_column.

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="number1_1" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             Foreground="Ivory"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center">4332.84</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="number1_2" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             Foreground="Ivory"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center">4201.62</TextBlock>
```

Now i could make 30 events in the code behind, one for every 'button' but then every event is almost the same and I dont think that is the right/propper way to do it.

I read some Stackoverflow articles where people said it was possible to attach more buttons to one event. My plan was to load every Border into a List of Borders at initialize, call this list in the general event and load the Borders that have the same row as the Textblocks of the calculations.

Is this the right way to do it ore is there a more optimal way to do it?

Regards Gijs

Comment: Is this perhaps something that may be better suited to a control like `DataGrid` instead?

Comment: @ChrisW., for this Silverlight project i'm obliged to write it like this in xaml and make it dynamic with C#. It's actualy a school task and other functions do work, i'm just stuck with this one because I don't want to write to much unnecessary code.

Comment: It already sounds like you have unnecessary code amigo, I would look into `DataGrid` or at least something you could template and single out your rows with like `ItemsControl`